# Using standalone infinispan (7.1.1 version) and infinispan is shutting down

Tags: infinispan

I am using standalone infinispan server on linux. We have bundled the infinispan version 7.1.1.Final and its deployed on RHEL7 VM along with one service which is dependent on infinispan server.

During upgrade, we could see that the infinispan server comes online but after few minutes it shuts down causing dependent service to stop and VM to stop.

Later, when we try to bring up the VM and issue get resolved.

This is an intermittent issue seen during upgrades only.

**Logs - **

```
2022-11-02 22:43:06,618 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
2022-11-02 22:43:06,623 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017521: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2022-11-02 22:43:06,710 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017520: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to /<VM_IP>:<VM_Port>
2022-11-02 22:43:06,713 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017506: Undertow 1.0.15.Final stopping
2022-11-02 22:43:06,734 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010282: Stopped default cache from clustered container
2022-11-02 22:43:06,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010282: Stopped ___hotRodTopologyCache cache from clustered container
2022-11-02 22:43:06,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010282: Stopped ___protobuf_metadata cache from clustered container
2022-11-02 22:43:06,758 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel clustered
2022-11-02 22:43:06,770 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000082: Stopping the RpcDispatcher for channel clustered
2022-11-02 22:43:06,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015950: JBoss Infinispan Server 7.1.1.Final (WildFly 8.1.0.Final) stopped in 335ms
```

kindly provide some insights for this investigation.

Comment: There isn't much there to help us understand what is happening: it looks like a regular shutdown. Version 7.1.1 is old and unsupported. You should really consider upgrading.

Comment: What can be different factors that can lead to shutdown ?

Comment: Shutdown of the WildFly-based server can happen for a number of reasons: 

* manually initiated via the CLI/Console

* receiving SIGTERM

* some missing subsystem (but there would be ample logging)

* broken configuration (again, logging would show it)